# bash: cd: linux: No such file or directory when installing zen kernel

Tags: bash, kernel

I was following these steps (http://apcmag.com/how-to-improve-gaming-performance-on-your-linux-machine.htm/) when, at step 6, to run

> cd linux

gave me

> bash: cd: linux: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type

which  is the "No such file or directory" error in french.

EDIT: The outputs of ls and ls -l:[Terminal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufz2u.png)

Comment: It looks like the soft link created in step 5 doesn't exist. [edit] your question to include the output of `ls -l` to see what is in `/usr/src`

Comment: OK you've created the link, but it doesn't point to a directory, where is zen-kernel-3.8-master.zip ?

Comment: I'ts on my Downads (Téléchargements) folder. Actually, I'm using the zen-kernel-4.7-master version, but I did replaced the version's number before entering the command in step 4, from _unzip /home/[username]/Downloads/zen-kernel-3.8-master.zip_ to unzip _/home/mateotabeira/Téléchargements/zen-kernel-4.7-master.zip_

Comment: Does `/home/mateotabeira/Téléchargements/zen-kernel-4.7-master` exist?

Comment: Yes, it does exists as a compressed zip. Do you mean as a folder?

Comment: Yeah, the `unzip` command in step 4 should have created a directory.

Comment: lIt didn't exist as a folder. I unzipped it manually and tried _cd linux_ again, but still not found. I don't know if it's useful, but Im' using Linux Mint 17.3

Comment: So now that you have unzipped the file `/home/mateotabeira/Téléchargements/zen-kernel-4.7-master.zip`, there should be a folder at `/home/mateotabeira/Téléchargements/zen-kernel-4.7-master` is that there?

Comment: Yes. it's there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have a different zen kernel version to the instructions, your soft link has been created to point to the wrong location. First delete the  'hanging' soft link:

```
cd /usr/src
rm linux
```

So long as you have `unzip`ped the .zip file to `/home/mateotabeira/Téléchargements/zen-kernel-4.7-master` the following command should work while you are in `/usr/src`:

```
ln -s /home/mateotabeira/Téléchargements/zen-kernel-4.7-master linux
```

Check that the soft link is correct with:

```
ls -lh linux
```

The output should show  a line with something like:

```
lrwxrwx 1 mateo mateo Sep 12 14:49 linux -> /home/mateotabeira/Téléchargements/zen-kernel-4.7-master
```

Now your `cd` command should work.

Comment: Worked like a charn.